# app engine python submit+display

Tags: google-app-engine

im new to google app engine with python
here is my html file where in jquery i write this

```
 $("a.display").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:800, innerHeight:550});
```

on this add button i want my current data save in database and then popup the saved record which i added.
my ques is how can i save data and then display in a lightbox popup.??

```
class DisplayAddHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("worksss")

        data_key_display = self.request.get('patients_id')
        key = self.request.get('key')
        patient_print_display = PatientInfo.get_by_id(int(data_key_display),parent=None)
        results_print_display = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM PatientMeds WHERE patientinfo_ID=" + data_key_display)
        results_patientalerts_print_display = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM PatientAlerts WHERE patientinfo_ID=" + data_key_display)

    template_values = {
    'patient_display': patient_print_display,
    'meds_display': results_print_display,
    'alert_display': results_patientalerts_print_display,

    }

    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'display.html')        
    self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

now i want when i save record.. it will saved successfully and after saving it will display the record which i have added on one click.(i mean on submit button it will save record + display)
 m having confusion as how can i saved and display on same button..
plz help me..
thanx in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You should use either jquery [form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) or [.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to submit the data and then in the success function add your code to display the colorbox.